# What is shortcut to rename a file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, function-keys

When I try to rename a file in Windows 7 by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, my screen gets darker. If I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, it gets brighter.

What is the keyboard shortcut to rename a file in Windows 7?

Comment: Do you have an Fn key and have you tried pressing that as well?

Comment: Are you using a laptop? If you are you will need to press the FN key to enable the function keys rather than the media keys, your higher function keys probably alter the volume

Comment: @deveneyi As far as *will need to*, that depends on the laptop (not saying you're wrong, but that may not apply to future/other readers). For HP Pavilion laptops, the default `fn` state is controlled by a BIOS option (http://askubuntu.com/a/96009).

Comment: I always use this tried and tested method:

Click the file name, wait half a second, click it again. Type new name... Presto!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Function lock must be on. Try holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button when you press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Just hold on <kbd>Alt</kbd> button for almost 2 seconds after selecting the file.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this one! 